# CPU thermal throttle counters

Tags: linux, cpu, hardware

In each CPU device directory (`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*`) there is a directory called `thermal_throttle` that contains two counters called:

`core_throttle_count`

`package_throttle_count`

**What are the meanings of these counters?**

The results I'm seeing seem to be contradicting my initial understanding of those counters given their descriptive names or I'm just missing something.

I have a laptop with a single quad-core Intel CPU w/ hyperthreading.  So eight logical CPUs overall.  The values of the two previously mentioned counters are:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/package_throttle_count`:

`1635649
1635647
1635649
1635648
1635648
1635650
1635650
1635649`

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/core_throttle_count`:

`0
368902
0
1288449
0
368902
0
1288451`

My understanding of 'package' was that it referred to the entire CPU chip/socket.  Thus, I would have expected the `package_throttle_count` values to be all equal, but instead, there are four unique values, albeit very close in value.  At first, I thought maybe the values could just be changing between each call to `cat` for each CPU, but they are pretty much static.

Then for the `core_throttle_count` I have four zeros and four other non-zero values.  I would have expected an equal counter value on each CPU that share a physical core.

Comment: A similar question here: https://superuser.com/questions/459354/the-meaning-of-thermal-throttle-counters-and-package-power-limit-notifications-i